# How to get struct datatype similar to value_counts() return in polars?

Tags: python-polars

I am trying to combine **two columns** row wise and get something similar to what `value_counts()` returns in `polars`.

I have tried to use the `to_struct` but that didn't give the result that I expected.

data:

```
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({
    "tags": ["c", "a", "b", "d"],
    "vals":[4,3,1,1] 
})

df.to_struct
```

```
<bound method DataFrame.to_struct of shape: (4, 2)
┌──────┬──────┐
│ tags ┆ vals │
│ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ str  ┆ i64  │
╞══════╪══════╡
│ c    ┆ 4    │
│ a    ┆ 3    │
│ b    ┆ 1    │
│ d    ┆ 1    │
```

Expected Result:

```
│ struct[2] │
╞═══════════╡
│ {"c",4}   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ {"a",3}   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ {"b",1}   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ {"d",1}   │
```

Not sure how can I do that as I have already tried to convert into `struct` datatype

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`to_struct`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.to_struct.html#polars.DataFrame.to_struct) is a method that needs to be called with `()`.

Comment: I tried that before posting and got an error but now after reading your answer realized I didn't pass the argument `.to_struct("tags")`. Thanks for helping out !!